# Azure with Selenium WebDriver errors

Tags: azure, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed my application to Azure Web App succesfully. It use Selenium WebDriver with Chrome (a portable version, because I need the binaries), but when I try to use this component I get the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location D:\home\site\wwwroot\Portable\GoogleChromePortable.exe
```

I already tried everything I saw over the internet but if I solve this message with this argument,
--remote-debugging option=XXXX then I got the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (chrome not reachable)
```

I guees this is because this port is not open in Azure...

Someone has faced this problem, and has solve it?

Pd: In a local environtment (my pc, or own server) it works.

Comment: if you need any port rather than 80, 443 it won't work in App Service (Web App).

Comment: I just figure it out that these problems were related to chrome.exe which does not run on Azure, working on solve it.

Comment: I guess the only way would be package everything with Docker containers and run then on ACI or Containers for WebApp

Comment: Yeah that's my next approach. Tank you! I will update this if works.

Comment: Would you get the same testing coverage by running it with headless mode enabled?

Comment: Yeah, it happened the same with the headless mode

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the Azure WebApps Sandbox restrictions - The standard/native Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available. You may leverage *container based Azure App Service* for your scenario.

Adding more information on this topic:

As mentioned in this document - [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) - Unsupported frameworks -PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI.

The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is through the already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports; applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from the internet.

If your app makes use of any COM components, these will need to be rewritten in managed code and deployed with the site or application. Furthermore, if your app cannot be migrated directly to App Service, consider App Service using Windows Containers, which enables usage of the GAC, COM components, MSIs, full access to .NET FX APIs, DirectX, and more.

Checkout these documents for more details on this topic:

[Run a custom Linux container in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker-go)

[Run a custom Windows container in Azure (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container)